# MySQL Remove part of string after specific character

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I do got a database named "MAPPINGS" with about 23.000 rows I need to replace becouse of a mistake. Is there any query to achieve the following:.

```
UPDATE MAPPINGS SET MAIN = 'firt part' WHERE USERID = '1578' AND MAIN LIKE 'first part >%'
```

The problem is that "first part" is every time something else. I just need to remove everyhing after the ">" than the MAPPINGS are correct.

Or can this only be done by a PHP script? while select * from mappings where userid = '1578' and then the update query. I hope there will be a query to achieve this.

Comment: try this : UPDATE MAPPINGS SET MAIN = 'firt part' WHERE USERID = '1578' AND MAIN LIKE %>%'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL using `substring_index()`:

```
UPDATE MAPPINGS
    SET MAIN = SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAIN, '>', 1)
    WHERE MAIN LIKE '%>%' AND USERID = '1578';
```

Comment: Thank you can assign this as the answers in 6m will do that.